# convert api string to JSON in swift or objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json, api, swift2

hi i'm getting following string(text/html) from my api request.

```
 let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    let res =   NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var jsonStr = res

        //here 'res' will be {status: 1, userid: "447", store_code: "930"}

        var data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        var localError: NSError?
        var json: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError)

        println("json res \(json)") // 'json' here is nil

        if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
             let weather = dict["status"] as? [AnyObject]
                println(weather)

        }

    }
```

//following is the text/html response from api request

{status: 1, userid: "447", store_code: "930"}

So how can i convert this text/html response string to JSON.
 When i try to use   NSJSONSerialization it gave fatal error or nil.
 Can anybody help me how can i solve this issue in swift or objective-c?

Comment: 1. Please add the code you use to deserialize it. 2. Please add the error you get.

Comment: Please remember to add the error. (2)

Answer (score 0):

JSON specification requires all keys of dictionaries as quoted strings.
This wraps all keys in double quotes with regex

```
let str = "{status: 1, userid: \"447\", store_code: \"930\"}"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\w+(?=: )", options: nil, error: nil)!
let jsonString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, count(str)), withTemplate: "\"$0\"")
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [JSONJoy](https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy-Swift) to extract those json's elements to DAO.